# Custom Popup control not closing

Tags: wpf, button, popup, controls

I'm trying to create a custom dropdown control that acts like a ComboBox, such that the Popup opens when you click mouse down (not up), and closes when you click outside of the control.

The problem is that it only behaves if I set ClickMode to "Release". But what I really want is ClickMode="Press", such that the Popup opens on MouseDown instead of MouseUp.

But when I set it to ClickMode="Press", the popup won't close when you click outside the control.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Usage :

```
          <StackPanel>
            <local:CustomDropdown Width="200"
                                  Height="50"
                                  Content="Custom!" />

            <ComboBox Width="200"
                      Margin="20"> 
                <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>C</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

Class :

```
internal class CustomDropdown : ContentControl
{
    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomDropdown), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Xaml :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomDropdown}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                              ClickMode="Press"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Popup StaysOpen="False"
                                       Placement="Bottom"
                                       IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <Border Background="White"
                                            BorderBrush="Black"
                                            BorderThickness="1"
                                            Padding="50">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Popup!" />
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You already have a working answer. However, finding the parent `Window` and parent `ToggleButton` can impact performance (depending on the depth of the visual tree).
As an alternative solution I suggest to focus on handling the `Popup` instead.

There are two conditions that prevent the `Popup` from closing itself: the button is configured with the `ButtonBase.ClickMode` set to `ClickMode.Pressed` AND the user is not clicking anything focusable inside the Popup.

If one of those two conditions evaluates to *false* (=> `ClickMode.Release` or the *user* has moved focus inside the `Popup`) your code will work as you would expected it to work.
Note that in order to allow the user to move focus inside the `Popup`, there must be a child that is focusable (`UIElement.Focusable` is set to `true` - it's `false` by default for most controls that don't require user interaction). For example, `TextBlock` is not focusable by default.

Because you want to keep the button configured to raise the `Click` event on mouse button press, you  have to move the focus manually. But when you set it manually, the `Popup` won't receive a mouse click to setup itself to watch the focus. Therefore, you will end up closing the `Popup` manually (taking away the related control from the `Popup`).

The following example closes the `Popup` by observing the `Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElement` event to identify when the focus has moved away from the `CustomDropdown` control (mouse click outside the `Popup`):

**CustomDropdown.cs**

```cs
internal class CustomDropdown : ContentControl
{
  public bool IsOpen
  {
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsOpen",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(CustomDropdown),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsOpenChanged));

  public CustomDropdown()
  {
    Mouse.AddPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementHandler(this, OnPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElement);
  }

  private static void OnIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    bool isOpen = (bool)e.NewValue;
    if (isOpen)
    {
      _ = Mouse.Capture(d as IInputElement, CaptureMode.SubTree);
    }
    else
    {
      _ = Mouse.Capture(null);
    }
  }

  // Manually close the Popup if click is recorded outside the CustomDropdown/Popup 
  private void OnPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElement(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
  {
    SetCurrentValue(IsOpenProperty, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to work for me. If I click outside the popup (e.g the main window background) it doesn't close the popup.

Comment: You have to click on something that can receive focus. The `StaysOpen` property controls the focus tracking behavior. If the focus moves out of the Popup and `StaysOpen` is set to `false`, then the Popup will close itself. The window background does not accept focus. Usually the user clicks on another UI element for example a button. Usually, the Popup opens on top of other UI elements.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I am trying to get behaviour that acts like a ComboBox, where you can click anywhere outside, even a non-focusable element such as the window background. I have just been looking at the reference source for the inbuilt WPF ComboBox, and they use  Mouse.Capture(comboBox, CaptureMode.SubTree). So I think thats the path I shall try. Trouble is, they use lots of internal Microsoft helper methods that are not exposed.

Comment: I know the implementation. My example basically does the same: find focusable element and move focus. The mouse capturing is used to generate the click event. It tracks mouse down and captures the mouse. This is done to avoid missing the mouse up event in case the user moves the mouse away from the ComboBox (while the button is still pressed) and the release it while over some other control.

Comment: @wforl I have finally updated the solution. It is now cleanly implemented. I now capture the mouse and handle the `Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElement` instead. I'd say the current solution is really clean and kind of mimics the original ComboBox behavior/implementation. I have also removed the optional logic to move the focus. the code has become much more compact and very clean now (reduced the required lines of code to a handful). Just let me know if you need more help.

Comment: wow, nice work. I have now marked this as the answer. It does look suspiciously simple though!? what's missing? :) ... as an aside, is there any reason not to use ReleaseMouseCapture()? instead of  Mouse.Capture(null)?

Comment: Thank you. The simplicity makes the solution so elegant in my opinion. No, as you probably already know, ReleaseMouseCapture is just a wrapper around Mouse.Capture(null). I don't wanted to mix the APIs. That's all.

Comment: One issue I noticed in my particular case was that I need a  ReleaseMouseCapture(); when the IsOpen is changed to false (such as when a value is selected), else the mouse is captured until you next click something else

Comment: Good point. I have moved the capture release from `OnPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElement` to `OnIsOpenChanged`. Thanks for helping to improve the code.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and found another (lighter) solution:
Just add the below line of code within the constructor of your control:

```
Mouse.Capture(null);
```

This releases the current mouse capture, that still belongs to your button being still not released when you build your popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work as expected with `ClickMode.Press`, you should programmatically set the `IsOpen` property to `false` whenever you want to the close the `Popup`. For example whenever you detect a click outside of the `ToggleButton`.

You could for example handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the parent window in your control. Something like this:

```
internal class CustomDropdown : ContentControl
{
    private ToggleButton _toggleButton;

    public CustomDropdown()
    {
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _toggleButton = GetTemplateChild("toggleButton") as ToggleButton;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        window.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnWindowPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        window.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= OnWindowPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private void OnWindowPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButton toggleButton = FindParent<ToggleButton>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
        if (toggleButton != _toggleButton)
            IsOpen = false;
    }

    private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        var parentT = parent as T;
        return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
    }

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomDropdown), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

}

**XAML:**

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" ...
```